# How to fix quadruple screen in teamviewer?

Tags: 12.04, server, display, remote, teamviewer

When I connect with my remote Ubuntu server (from Windows 7) everything I get is a quadruple cut-off image of something that from far looks like a desktop environment:

[image]

I have googled this error and have still no answer nor any idea why this problem occurs. I already tried common solutions like rebooting, reinstalling, updating app and system, check the network ports and closed all unimportant tasks.

The Ubuntu Version is 12.04.4

Did anybody have the same problem and/or knows the solution?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and found the solution here: [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/FAQ](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/FAQ#Which_driver_should_be_used_for_Xorg.3F)

You need to create file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/60-teamviewer-fix.conf` contents:

```
Section "Monitor"
        Identifier   "Monitor0"
        VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
        ModelName    "Monitor Model"
        HorizSync       20.0 - 50.0
        VertRefresh     40.0 - 80.0
        Option          "DPMS"

EndSection

Section "Device"
        Identifier  "Card0"
        Driver      "vesa"
        VendorName  "KVM - std"
        BoardName   "GD 5446"
        BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier "Screen0"
        Device     "Card0"
        Monitor    "Monitor0"
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Modes "1600x1200"
        EndSubSection
EndSection
```

After that reboot your Ubuntu server and problem will be solved.